# maven plugin install:install-file error

Tags: java, maven

I use install:install-file to install jar to my local repository.My pom.xml is written as follow:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
    <id>install-paho</id>
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>install-file</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <file>${basedir}/lib/paho.jar</file>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>paho</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

You can find that I binding it to phase 'generate-resources'.And then,I use order `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.It works very well and the jar was copied to my local repository.But when I use order `mvn install:install-file` I got the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (default-cli) on project xxx: 
The parameters 'file' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

The error messages when use `mvn compile`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project android-engine: Could not resolve dependencies    for project com.youku.wireless:android-engine:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.eclipse:paho:jar:1.0.0 in spring-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone) ->   [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]     http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have bound `install:install-file` goal to the `generate-sources` phase, you should run `mvn compile` or `mvn install` or such to use the defined configurations.

`mvn eclipse:eclipse` works because maven runs the `generate-sources` phase prior to invoking `eclipse:eclipse`.

**Edit:**  From the comments it looks like you want to use the locally available `paho.jar` in your project by first installing it to your local repo in the `generate-sources` phase and thereafter use it as a `dependency` in your project.

This is not going to work since maven checks for availability of `dependencies` before it starts executing its life-cycle goals.

You could manually install it one-time using `mvn install:install-file` outside the context of the pom.  Better still you could deploy it to a `repository manager` and then access it like any other dependency.

However, if you still want to go down this path, an alternate approach would be to specify the dependency with a `system` scope providing the path of the jar. Refer to [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies).

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
      <artifactId>paho</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0/version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/paho.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I can't understand.I run `mvn compile` but still error.Am I miss something?

Comment: @plucury.  Could you edit your question and post maven output when you run `mvn compile`?

Comment: @plucury. The error is different now. maven is complaining about missing `paho.jar` during compilation. This seems to indicate `paho.jar` did not get installed.  Can you check if the artifact is present in the local repository at the correct location?

Comment: There is no `paho.jar` in my local repository.It seems `install:install-file` hasn't been involved.

Comment: @plucury.  Updated answer assuming the use-case you have.  Please edit/correct the question otherwise.