# Installing a file to a Maven repo on the fly

Tags: maven, dependencies

I'm running Maven 3.0.3.  I have a JAR that is not part of any online repository.  I keep it in lib/quickbase.jar of my project.  Ideally, when building to a project, I would like to have this automatically installed to the local repo without having to run a "mvn install:install-file" first.  I found this and included it in my pom.xml ...

```
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <id>install-quickbase-jar</id>
                                            <phase>compile</phase>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <file>${basedir}/lib/quickbase.jar</file>
                                                    <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                                                    <groupId>quickbase</groupId>
                                                    <artifactId>quickbase</artifactId>
                                                    <version>1.0</version>
                                                    <packaging>jar</packaging>
                                                    <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                                            </configuration>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>install-file</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

The dependency in my pom is

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>quickbase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>quickbase</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

However, running Maven results in

```
mvn clean test
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project didoclient: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.mainco.myco:didoclient:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: quickbase:quickbase:jar:1.0,
```

Is it possible to have this dependency installed on the fly and if so, how can I adjust the above?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to install a dependency on the fly since Maven checks dependencies before it starts going through lifecycle phases, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10946205/658907) for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

THe best solution is to install this file only once into your local repository (command line mvn install:install-file) but the best solution is to put this into a repository manager and afterwards you can use as a usual dependency.

You could try to change the lifecycle-phase for the install plugin may be generate-sources or earlier like initialize but i assume that this won't work either.

Comment: I may be asking for something that's not possible to do -- if that's the case, just let me know.  I tried changing the lifecycle phase but that didn't work.

Comment: That's what i expected. So best solution is either manually install the file into the local repository but better is to use a repository manager.